# How can I check if some IIS modules are present

Tags: c#, iis

I am working on an installer and am looking to programatically check in IIS (7 and above) to see if certain modules are present.

This will have to work on Windows server 2008 R2 and above.

I am looking for AppWarmupModule and DynamicCompressionModule.

Any info or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load the contents of the file:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
```

You can put it into a XML document and use xPath to find

```
<configuration><system.webServer><globalModules><add name="DynamicCompressionModule"
```

or string-parse or Regex the content otherwise to find out whether the strings you are looking at are present.

Comment: Peter, thanks for the answer, its exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Solving similar problem for IIS10, but also for installation to remote servers. Direct reading xml file is not solution for me.

In my case, I need to find if AspNetCoreModuleV2 is installed or not, but this should works for every module.

Based on [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/globalmodules/) I used approach below. It returns list of globalModules in applicationHost.config for selected server. (with using Microsoft.Web.Administration)

```
    internal static ConfigurationElementCollection GetModules(string remoteServerName = null)
    {
        ServerManager mgr;
        mgr = string.IsNullOrEmpty(remoteServerName) ? new ServerManager() : ServerManager.OpenRemote(remoteServerName);

        Configuration config = mgr.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
        ConfigurationSection globalModulesSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/globalModules");
        ConfigurationElementCollection globalModulesCollection = globalModulesSection.GetCollection();

        return globalModulesCollection;
    }
```

And then simple enumerate:

```
        ConfigurationElementCollection modules = GetModules();
        foreach (var item in modules)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.Attributes["name"].Value);
            // do whatever you want
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Helped me a lot with .NET 6 using Microsoft.Web.Administration nuget package.